# Racing scenario regarding to multithreading programming

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I'm designing a net game so I have a client with one listening thread to things that are coming from server, also the server has a listening thread which is listening to messages from the client.

In the one of the Client panels I do the following:
sending some message to server and after two lines of code from the same place do it again with other function.
The result is a run of code that sometimes works well and sometimes throw an exception.
The exception is being thrown at the line of one of the sending functions on the client panel.

*Note: if I place `Thread.sleep(1000);` between the two sends than no exception is thrown,but as you know it's a bad solution..

** The two functions that sends info to the one and only server thread are:

```
ClientCommunicationThread.UpdateServerOfTimeEnded  
ClientCommunicationThread.SendRequestToClosePlayerThreadAndRemoveItFromPlayersOnServer
```

How can I solve this problem
Thanks.

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:181)
    at GUI.ClientCommunicationThread.UpdateServerOfTimeEnded(ClientCommunicationThread.java:850)
    at GUI.JPanelMainGame$2.actionPerformed(JPanelMainGame.java:312)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:271)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:201)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:180)
    at GUI.ClientCommunicationThread.SendRequestToClosePlayerThreadAndRemoveItFromPlayersOnServer(ClientCommunicationThread.java:824)
    at GUI.JPanelMainGame$2.actionPerformed(JPanelMainGame.java:325)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:271)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:201)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption : This happens because you are using same socket object for both functions, And both functions wants to write something to socket output stream. I hope I am right on this. Based on this my go would be using synchronisation. Below link will guide you through some of the way to have locks on objects so that two different thread cannot access same object together. You create implicit lock and than release when you done with it. :) And of course you can create two different threads to calls two different functions. ( More safer...)

Link : [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Hope this will help you to solve.

Comment: I tried some things but still it doesn't work. I try to think why both functions want to write at the same time it couldn't be because they are coming one after another, so after one send should be the second send. I'm adding more relevant code

Comment: Sorry, I cant paste more code for some reason it says that it is not indented, well far as netbeans "see" it, it's passing compilation !Some of this editing rules are so infantile sometimes..

Comment: It would be hard for me to diagnose Without code :). I suggested synchronisation because you mentioned your Thread.sleep() test. Which clearly shows that code is using socket to write togeather. Or just give me a psuedo reference about what basically your code does I might think a way around :)

Comment: Hi thanks, but this post is not updated the thread.sleep give exception also apparently. Some people told me that the problem is because I try to write to DataOutputStream from within the event dispatch thread. I will be very glad if you can see my new post about the subject which is updated and detailed enought I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706527/sending-information-over-dataoutputstream-throws-exception