# Sending information over DataOutputStream throws exception

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, timer

Consider you have the following code implementation of a timer in a net game:

```
public void DefineTimer()
    {
            Action updateClockAction = new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                    //System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

                     JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Handwriting", 1, 36));
                     JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setForeground(Color.red);
                     JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setText(Integer.toString(JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds));

                    if( JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds >0)
                    {
                         JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds--;
                    }
                    else if ( JPanelMainGame.this.m_TimerTotalSeconds == 0)
                    {
                       // System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                        JPanelMainGame.this.m_Timer.stop();
                        JPanelMainGame.this.jLabelSeconds.setText("0");
                        JPanelMainGame.this.jButtonFinish.setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println("after JbuttonFinish set visble false");
                        System.out.println("!m_WasGameDecisived: "+!m_WasGameDecisived);
                       // System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                        JPanelGameApplet gameApplet = (JPanelGameApplet) getTopLevelAncestor();
                        //Checking whether time ended for both players and no solution was recieved

                        if(gameApplet.GetJPanelChooseGame().GetGameType() == eGameType.Net)
                        {

                            gameApplet.GetClinetThread().UpdateServerOfTimeEnded();
                            System.out.println("After Update");
                            if (!m_WasGameDecisived)
                            {
                                // System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                                System.out.println("Tie - No one had a solution in the given time");


                                gameApplet.GetClinetThread().SendRequestToClosePlayerThreadAndRemoveItFromPlayersOnServer();
                                System.out.println("After SendRequestToClosePlayerThread");
                                gameApplet.GetClinetThread().CloseSocket();
                                System.out.println("After CloseSocket");
                                Menu.BrowseTo(PanelMenuNumber.k_ChooseGame, JPanelMainGame.this.getParent());
                                //askUserForAnotherRoundLeaveTableOrExitProgram();//////////////////////////////////////////////To implement
                            }
                        }
                        else if(gameApplet.GetJPanelChooseGame().GetGameType() == eGameType.Single)
                        {
                            JPanelMainGame.this.showPopUpSelectionBar();

                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            m_Timer = new Timer(1000, updateClockAction);
    }
```

I have added these functions (which write to the same DataOutputStream:

```
gameApplet.GetClinetThread().UpdateServerOfTimeEnded();

gameApplet.GetClinetThread().SendRequestToClosePlayerThreadAndRemoveItFromPlayersOnServer();
```

After adding them I get inconsistent exceptions: 
Sometimes I get exception in the client because one of the functions, or both or not having any exception at all.
Please help me figure out the problem
Example for exceptions I get from time to time:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:181)
        at GUI.ClientCommunicationThread.UpdateServerOfTimeEnded(ClientCommunicationThread.java:851)
        at GUI.JPanelMainGame$2.actionPerformed(JPanelMainGame.java:313)
        at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:271)
        at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:201)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:180)
        at GUI.ClientCommunicationThread.SendRequestToClosePlayerThreadAndRemoveItFromPlayersOnServer(ClientCommunicationThread.java:825)
        at GUI.JPanelMainGame$2.actionPerformed(JPanelMainGame.java:327)
        at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:271)
        at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:201)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to make a network call on the EDT

Comment: I think that I can't avoid it, because I need to do something specific if the time ran out and only than: like updating the server that the time was over and some other things that should be carried out only when the time end. Do you have any idea of how I can do such a call from timer thread? and if not what should i do?

Comment: You would better refactor your network call to a `Runnable` and call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` in your `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: mmm ,can you give an example code, I thought that I mustn't do networking in EDT according to the first comment

Comment: `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /*your current networking code*/ 
        }
    });
}`

Comment: okay but invoke and wait will cause the network stuff to be done on EDT, and John Vint said I should avoid it, correct me if I mistake

Comment: After some searching now I am not sure whether it is wise to follow my previous advice. Maybe it is better to create an `java.util.concurrent.Executor` in your app's startup and in the `actionPerformed` method just submit your `Runnable` to the `Executor`. That is, replace `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` with `executor.execute`.

Comment: @JohnVint: What is your opinion?

Comment: @saintali: your initial recommendation is incorrect as that will force the socket communication to be done on the EDT, exactly what we don't want to have happen. Better to use a SwingWorker.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I don't know what is swing worker but it sounds like its thread working also on EDT so, same problem I think.. If I'm wrong I will be very happy to see how to convert my code to what you said or another solution of how to get out of the event dispatch thread from within the swing.Timer code

Comment: @JavaSa: Look it up before you make the wrong assumption. It helps create a background thread ***off*** of the EDT but allowing for communication with the EDT through publish/process methods. As for converting your code -- hard for any of us to tell as it is very convoluted and looks like it should be refactered quite a bit, if only so that we'll understand it, and also to help separate model from control from view.

Comment: Do you have some simple example of use of swing worker?

Comment: Sorry, it's called a SwingWorker (no space), and no it's not the only way to do a background thread as any plain vanilla background thread will work, but it does some advantages including publish/process as noted above, and it's a Future so it can return something. It has great PropertyChange support as well. you can find more about it here: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: The timer on the client is shown as consistently updating label, so I need to do all of the label updating from EDT, but networking from the non EDT thread is it possible with SwingWorker? So regarding the current code can I ran a code in non EDT for checking the timer state as I did + doing networking and also calling some label changes which need to be ran on EDT

Comment: possible duplicate of [Racing scenario regarding to multithreading programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700526/racing-scenario-regarding-to-multithreading-programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'From within a Swing timer' indicates a design flaw as per the comments to your question, but the exception itself is simply a network error and has nothing to do with Swing at all. There is a Microsoft Knowledge Base article about it, which you should read, but in brief this exception *with this error text* indicates that the local TCP stack has given up writing to that connection due to prior network send problems.

Comment: okay thanks , I'll try to shorten the story and to explain my design more generally. I'm implementing a net game in which I have an applet client and server.Two Players are playing, and the winner is the player who had a solution at an earlier time(of the count down Timer) I thought that it would be wise to put the Timer on the Client applet so he will see the timer. I don't think It would be wise to put timer on server because it should be equal to what the client see and to start in the same time.. All the problem is because of Tie scenario- and I see it when the timer seconds is 0

Comment: so, when it happen I need first to update the server that time ran out- else it could bring some other scenario which I don't want, and I want to close the client thread on server (which is opened for each client in the connection time) before I close the client itself

Comment: By the way, Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested that I'll use swing worker, but I don't familiar with it, is it the only solution?

Comment: @JavaSa Any technique that uses a separate thread for the networking will do. When you get any exception other than SocketTimeoutException and one other that I can't remember but that doesn't arise here, you must close then socket, it is dead.

Comment: @JavaSa, As I said in your other post, again it seems you need to wait until you use that socket object. By any mean...efficiently....

Comment: @Brogrammer: I've already tried some ways of synchronization and it didn't work. In some checks I did I got into conclusion that the problem is because the presence of each function of the two alone,not necessarily together..( if you put one of the functions with // then you will see you can still get exception so its should be something other that sync problems I guess.

Comment: @JavaSa This is all irrelevant. See my answer. The one you are presently commenting on. Your program structure is certainly at fault but it is not the cause of this exception.

Comment: @EJP: okay solved the problem! but how would you change things that won't be a fault in your view of this code. What is the main problem is it calling network from within an EDT? because I can solve it by starting a new thread that will not be on EDT and will do networking

Comment: @JavaSa that's exactly what I said above. The problem is that the blocking network operations will also block your UI.

Comment: @EJP: I just want to mention that my network operation are just two function that are writing an int to data output stream and they are taking place in the end of the game so fast that I don't think it freezes my GUI, which is anyway not so important in this stage. However does adding new thread from within the Timer code in this way to handle the communication in non EDT is fair enough?

Comment: new Thread()
 {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

      try
         {
            Communication handled here
         }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            }.start();